# query not applying custom score

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm making the next query, my problem is that the custom score (scrip_score) is not being applied. Am I doing something wrong?:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "tactics": [
              "user_id"
              "type_user",
              "browser_plugins",
              "cashback"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "script_score": {
      "script": "type_user === 2 ? 1 : 2"
    }
  },
  "from": "0",
  "size": 50,
  "sort": {
    "name": {
      "order": "desc",
      "ignore_unmapped": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `script_score` section in your query gets ignored. If you want it to be taken into account you need to wrap you existing `bool` query into a `function_score` query where you can use the `script_score` part as well.